Issue of default scripting plugin getting disabled
Hey I'm getting and error like this when i'm trying to run my app in android studio
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)

}
android {
    namespace = "com.example.androiddevelopmenttutorial"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.androiddevelopmenttutorial"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
           useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.14"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}

}
dependencies {
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

}
what am i doing wrong?

Have you ever found a solution to this?
